# Is there a SelectedIndex for an HTML5 DataList?

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

You can pick the current `option` of any `select` element:

```
mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex]
```

Can I do the same with a DataList? Something like this:

```
<input id = "input" list = "datalist" type = "text" />

<datalist id = "datalist">
    <option value = "No. 1"></option>
    <option value = "No. 2"></option>
    <option value = "No. 3"></option>
</datalist>

<script>
    var datalist = document.getElementById ("datalist");
    var input = document.getElementById ("input");

    input.addEventListener ("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {
            alert (datalist.options[datalist.selectedIndex]); // Example
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the datalist element is for providing autocomplete to inputs. It is a source of data, is hidden from the user, and multiple inputs may link to it. Therefore it doesn't make sense to have a `selectedIndex`.

Instead, you should simply check the `.value` of the input:

```
var datalist = document.getElementById ("datalist");
var input = document.getElementById ("input");

input.addEventListener ("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        alert(input.value);
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Beware: when user clicks on dropdown item from datalist (mouseclick), no event is fired (chrome21)

Comment: Should probably change the event listener to `input` since that'd work with the problem Dmitry posed too.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-datalist-element), `datalist` object doesn't have `selectedIndex` property. But you can find it's default option, which have `selected`. Or compare input's value to each option value and manually find the index.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i=0;i<datalist_id.options.length;i++)
    if (datalist_id.options[i].value == input_id.value) 
        {alert(datalist_id.options[i].innerText);break;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have data attributes in the above example like this,

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser" value="Internet Explorer">
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer" data-company="Microsoft">
    <option value="Firefox" data-company="Mozilla">
    <option value="Chrome" data-company="Google/Alphabet">
    <option value="Opera" data-company="Opera">
    <option value="Safari" data-company="Apple">
</datalist>
```

and you want to obtain the data-company attribute of the selected item,

using the loop above

```
for (var i=0;i<datalist_id.options.length;i++) {
    if (datalist_id.options[i].value == input_id.value) {
        // obtains the data-company attrbute
        console.log(datalist_id.options[i].getAttribute("data-company");
        alert(datalist_id.options[i].innerText);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a value to the input element. This will be shown to the user as the "default" value. If the user decides to change it, i.e. delete this value from the input field, then the list in the datalist will show up:

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser" value="Internet Explorer">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the script for getting index from `SelectedIndex` of `Datalist`. Html from @pingle60

```
let x = document.getElementById("browsers").options;
let input = document.querySelector('input');
input.onchange = getIndex;

function getIndex(e) {
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
        if (x[i].value == e.target.value) {
            return i;
            // alert('The index of SellectedIndex is : ' + i + ' and the value is : '  +x[i].value);
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```