# How to get data from a special attribute in datalist using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, datalist, html-datalist

I want to get the data inside "opt_id".
And the same code works when i use `selelct` tag insted of `datalist`.

**This is how my code looks like:**

```js
var get_data = document.getElementById("select_opt");
var dataIndex = get_data.options[get_data.selectedIndex].getAttribute("opt_id");
```

```html
<input id="optio_lists" list="options" placeholder="Search...">
<datalist id="select_opt">
<option opt_id="0"  label="Cricket">Cricket</option>
<option opt_id="1"  label="Football">Football</option>
<option opt_id="2"  label="Tennis">Tennis</option>
<option opt_id="3"  label="Basketball">AKITA</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Typo: `"select_op"` should be `"select_opt"`

Comment: `opt_id` is not a valid attribute. Use a `data-*` attribute for this -> `data-opt_id`

Answer (score 1):

In your script tag in the `get_data` variable at `document.getElementById()` you have misspelled the `id` - instead of `select_opt` you have written `select_op`.

Answer (score 0):

Data list is just a source of data and is different from a select box. Hence selectedIndex property doesn't makes sense here.

Check this link for more details - [Is there a SelectedIndex for an HTML5 DataList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724713/is-there-a-selectedindex-for-an-html5-datalist)

Comment: Yes, i got that. But the suggested one option is not giving me the value inside that "attribute(opt_id)". That is working fine in the "value" case. Thanks for your time !